# Our custom off topic close reasons need updating to HTTPS

Tags: support, bug, close-reasons

I found a spot on our site where links haven't been updated to HTTPS yet: our custom close reasons. The links in them still point to HTTP:// locations.

Here's an example:

[image: http links]

Comment: \*groan\*, that's annoying. They're a huge pain to update. Only Staff can update them in-place (that is, without them falling off all the posts). We'll have to bat-signal a CM.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I figured they might set up a bot to sweep through the network-wide close reasons and update them.

Comment: That's probably what they would end up doing, unless there really are very few.